# unable to call c++ functions in qt

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a shared library of the C++ application and I am able to call it using the test app. I want to write a Qt UI for this. I am not able to call the C++ functions directly. Only if I give name mangled function name it works.
Also if I create an object of the C++ class and  call a function of the class I am getting "undefined reference to " the function.
How can I call the C++ functions and create objects of C++ class and call functions on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include the path to the headers files. To do this in Qt Creator, modify your .pro file to include the following line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += path/to/header/files
```

you will notice that you MUST use the slash above... If you try using '\', it will not work.

Comment: thanks for the responses i added the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS and it worked

Comment: @prasad: if we have answered your question, please mark a correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're not correctly including the header files for the code you want to use. The "extra" features of QT don't stop all of the normal C++ features from working.